# Impementation Stack in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack

I have to implement a stack structure in C, but this code fail in main     when I assign "pila = initialize_stack();" why?
How i can do for this implementation or if this code is totally wrong how can implement stack in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100
//Define Struct
struct Stack {
    int dim;
    int array[MAX];
};

//Prototype Function
struct Stack inizialize_stack();        //inizialize a new empty Stack
void push(struct Stack pila, int num);  //insert element in Stack
int pop(struct Stack pila);             //extract element out of Stack
void printStack(struct Stack pila);     //Print Element in Stack

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct Stack pila; 
    pila =  inizialize_stacK();
    push(pila, 10);
    push(pila, 13);
    printStack(pila);
    return 0;

}

struct Stack inizialize_stack(){
    struct Stack pile;
    pile.dim = 0;
    return pile;
}
}
```

The compiler produces this error message:

```
/TestStack.c:20:7: error: assigning to 'struct Stack' from incompatible type 'int' pila = inizialize_stacK()
```

Comment: Please define "**fail**".

Comment: If you are on embedded device, you may get on stack overflow on start because `Stack` is quite big variable. Consider using global variable for stack store.

Comment: You have one extra brace at the end of the file! is that the problem?

Comment: /TestStack.c:20:7: error: assigning to 'struct Stack' from incompatible type 'int'
        pila =  inizialize_stacK();

Comment: You have a typo in your function call - `inizialize_stacK()` versus `inizialize_stack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, and that is a closeable question but

```
pila = inizialize_stacK();
                   /* ^ should be lower case */
```

You see, the error message is not a *undefined identifier error*, because the compiler is using *implicit function declaration* and it assumes that the **undeclared function** returns `int`, that's why the error message says *incompatible assignment*.

Force your compiler to use a recent standard, starting from [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) this should be a different error that would let you know what happened, i.e. would let you spot the typo.

Comment: thanks for compiler tip, now the code runs well

Comment: @SerPecchia Next time, ask a more specific question, include all the information that you can, but of course not too much.

Comment: sorry i'm new on StackOverflow. Thanks for all your tip

Comment: Don't have a function return a huge struct, not efficient. Use pointers.